# Get Longitude and Latitude from a Google Places Result

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xamarin.android, google-places-api

I am writing an Android App using Xamarin which uses Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps Nuget Package.  I need to get to a particular place on the map using the name of the place.  For this purpose I loaded Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places.  I am able to pass a partial place name to the GetAutocompletePredictionsAsync as so:

```
var autocompletePredictions = await 
PlacesClass.GeoDataApi.GetAutocompletePredictionsAsync(
                Adapter.googleApiClient, constraint.ToString(), 
                Adapter.bounds, Adapter.autoCompleteFilter);
```

The result I get back is basically a collection of IAutocompletePrediction.  The only item in this object that has to do with location is the PlaceId.  I cannot find any way to use this on the Google Maps API.  I tried seeing if I could get any more information by calling the GetPlaceById:

```
var place = PlacesClass.GeoDataApi.GetPlaceById(googleApiClient, item.PlaceId);
```

But I didn't see any location information at all in that result.  Does anyone know how to get LatLng information from the Google Places API?

Update:  I used information from several responses to get the answer:

```
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                PlaceBuffer places = await PlacesClass.GeoDataApi.GetPlaceByIdAsync(googleApiClient, item.PlaceId);

                if (places.Status.IsSuccess)
                {

                    foreach (var place in places)
                        try
                        {
                            //IPlace place = (IPlace)places.Get(0);

                            MarkOnMap(place.NameFormatted.ToString(), place.AddressFormatted.ToString(), place.LatLng);
                            UpdateCameraPosition(place.LatLng);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log.Error("WhatNow", ex.ToString());
                        }
                }

                places.Dispose();
            });
```

The odd thing was when I enumerated the places in the foreach, the place was an IPlace type.  However

```
IPlace place = (IPlace)places.Get(0);
```

Did not cast to an IPlace.  Who knows?  I just hope that Dispose() releases the buffer as recommended in the Docs.  Xamarin is always just a little different from Java.

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Have you tried `.getLatLng()` ? The place object should have that function.

Comment: Also just to make sure we are on the same page. The result in your question is a pending result, to get the actual Place object - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult

Comment: Try using `PlaceBuffer places = await PlacesClass.GeoDataApi.GetPlaceByIdAsync(googleApiClient, placeId)`, `IPlace place = places.FirstOrDefault()`, `place.AddressFormatted.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this, you can try this code.
I am using autoCompleteTextView.

```
dropLocationEt.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                Log.i(TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);
            /*
             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
              details about the place.
              */
                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(googleApiClient, placeId);
                placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            // Request did not complete successfully
                            Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                            places.release();
                            return;
                        }
                        // Get the Place object from the buffer.
                        final Place place = places.get(0);
                        latLngDrop = place.getLatLng();
                        StaticMethods.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
                        dropLocationEt.setSelection(0);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

From the latlngDrop, you can retrieve the lat and lng, eg: latlngDrop.getLatitude, latlngDrop.getLongitude